# Get data from object based in key in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When `data-person` has a value of `80` I want to show the content that is in the object with the matching key, ie. to access `{ "name": "Jhon Doe"}` and show in the HTML.

```
<div id="people" data-person="80"></div>
```

```js
var people = {"80": { "name": "Jhon Doe"}}
var obj = JSON.parse(people);
```

How I can get this? Thank You!

Comment: Do you want to access `{ "name": "Jhon Doe"}` ?

Comment: @Rayon yes! :).

Comment: @rory-mccrossan thanks for you edition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery `data()` and having multiples

```js
var people = {
  "80": {
    "name": "Jhon Doe"
  },
  "90": {
    "name": "Fred Flinstone"
  }
}


$('[data-person]').text(function() {
  return people[$(this).data('person')].name
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="people" data-person="80"></div>
<div id="people2" data-person="90"></div>
```

Comment: Use common classes on the children and do something like: `$('[data-person]').each(function(){ var person = people[$(this).data('person')]; $(this).find('.person-name').text(person.name);})`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to access a `object` which is property of an object.

Use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to access the value from `data-*` attribute and use [`Bracket` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the value.

Note: `JSON.parse` is not needed at all. Purpose of `JSON.parse` to parse `JSON(Text)` as `Object`

**Edit:** To set the text, use `jQuery.text` or `Element.textContent`

```js
var people = {
  "80": {
    "name": "Jhon Doe"
  }
};
var element = document.getElementById('people');
var key = element.dataset.person;
element.textContent = people[key].name;
```

```html
<div id="people" data-person="80"></div>
```